# Why doesn't Gamepad.GetCurrentReading() work?

Tags: raspberry-pi, uwp, windowsiot

I've created a UWP app that takes advantage of the `Windows.Gaming.Input` namespace, but when I deploy to my Raspberry Pi 2 B running Windows 10 IoT Core, the `Gamepad.GetCurrentReading()` method returns a default instance of the `GamepadReading`. (i.e. everything is `0`)

Debugging on my local machine seems to work. Is there anything additional needed to get this API working on my device?

P.S. I noticed that one of the samples [uses HidDevice](https://github.com/ms-iot/build2015-robot-kit/blob/develop/RobotApp/RobotApp/Controllers.cs#L148), so I'll look into that as an alternative in the mean time.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this; I'll check to see if it's a known limitation on the IoT builds.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterTorr-MSFT. Is there a more official place where I should file bugs like this?

Comment: The Windows Feedback app has a category for developer platform. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, this is an issue on IoT-only due to a timing bug; not sure when it will be fixed. Also only Xbox 360 controllers are supported at this time, not Xbox One.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my (incomplete) workaround. It's a drop-in replacement for the `Gamepad` class.

```cs
class HidGamepad
{
    static readonly List<HidGamepad> _gamepads = new List<HidGamepad>();
    GamepadReading _currentReading;

    static HidGamepad()
    {
        var deviceSelector = HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(0x01, 0x05);
        var watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(deviceSelector);
        watcher.Added += HandleAdded;
        watcher.Start();
    }

    private HidGamepad(HidDevice device)
    {
        device.InputReportReceived += HandleInputReportRecieved;
    }

    public static event EventHandler<HidGamepad> GamepadAdded;

    public static IReadOnlyList<HidGamepad> Gamepads
        => _gamepads;

    public GamepadReading GetCurrentReading()
        => _currentReading;

    static async void HandleAdded(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
    {
        var hidDevice = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(args.Id, FileAccessMode.Read);
        if (hidDevice == null) return;

        var gamepad = new HidGamepad(hidDevice);
        _gamepads.Add(gamepad);
        GamepadAdded?.Invoke(null, gamepad);
    }

    void HandleInputReportRecieved(
        HidDevice sender, HidInputReportReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        var leftThumbstickX = args.Report.GetNumericControl(0x01, 0x30).Value;
        var leftThumbstickY = args.Report.GetNumericControl(0x01, 0x31).Value;

        _currentReading = new GamepadReading
        {
            LeftThumbstickX = (leftThumbstickX - 32768) / 32768.0,
            LeftThumbstickY = (leftThumbstickY - 32768) / -32768.0
        };
    }
}
```